# printing max depth in Binary search tree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to obtain the max depth of a binary search tree however I believe the tree is counting wrong.

my code:

```
    def BST_maxdepth(root):
        curdepth = [1]
        maxdepth = [1]
        if root is None:
            return -1
        else:
            curdepth[0] = 1
            maxdepth[0] = 1
            if root.left is not None or root.right is not None:
                curdepth[0] += 1
                if curdepth[0] > maxdepth[0]:
                    maxdepth[0] = curdepth[0]
                BST_maxdepth(root.left)
                BST_maxdepth(root.right)
        return maxdepth[0]
```

classes & BST:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value


def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)

        if root.value < node.value:    # go to right
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)
```

tests:

```
r = Node(8)


a = Node(5)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(1)
d = Node(3)
e = Node(7)
```

output:

`2`

expected output:

`4`

Comment: Isn't your depth actually supposed to be 4?

Comment: sorry i used the wrong sample data that I was testing with but in this case you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something like...

```
def BST_maxdepth(root, depth=0):
    if root is None:
        return depth
    return max(BST_maxdepth(root.left, depth+1),
               BST_maxdepth(root.right, depth+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't updating `maxdepth` more than once.  Perhaps something like this:

```
left_depth = BST_maxdepth(root.left)
right_depth = BST_maxdepth(root.right)
maxdepth[0] = max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not carrying `curdepth` and `maxdepth` with you as you recurse, and they're not global. 
At each call to `BST_maxdepth`, you declare a new `curdepth` and `maxdepth`.

This means that the regardless of how deep your tree is, `maxdepth` will only ever be 2 (or 1 if the root has no children).

You could try either using an accumulator, or returning a value from each recursive call and building `maxdepth` that way.

Comment: yes you are right! Sorry I carry some of my c/c++ programming habits into python and declaring variables is different between the two so I tend to get confused

Answer (score 1):

Your `maxdepth` from each recursive step is not being passed to the parent step.

The information from

```
BST_maxdepth(root.left)
BST_maxdepth(root.right)
```

needs to be returned to the parent.

You are re-instantiating them at each level of the search:

```
 curdepth = [1]
 maxdepth = [1]
```